# efficient way of numpy array cache lookup?

Tags: numpy

suppose I have a boolean array, `mask = np.array([True, False, True, False])`
and every a few elements could form a cache key for some value lookup.

E.g. `intevals = (2, 2)` -> `CACHE[(0, (True, False))]->[.1,.2]` and `CACHE[(1, (True, False))]->[.2, .1]`

or `intevals = (1, 3)` -> `CACHE[(0, (True))]->[.1]` and `CACHE[(1, (False, True, False))]->[.2, .2, .1]`

since the output value shape would be the same as the mask, wondering what's the most efficient way to performing such caching lookup

Comment: assume python pandas?

Comment: Doesn't look like a `numpy` problem.

Comment: the mask in a numpy array and the desired value is another numpy array. not sure if that counts as a numpy problem. and pandas are also acceptable as long as the solution is performant